# POST запрос проходит тест в Postman но не проходит в Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

Есть следующий POST запрос:

```
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> newApplicationsRequest(
        @Valid @RequestPart("json") ApplicationsRequest newApplicationRequest,
        @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] file
)
```

Который обязательно отправляет JSON  и еще может в себе содержать файлы. В Postman`е данный запрос отрабатывает без ошибок но при тестировании в Swagger UI 2.0 дает 500 ошибку.

Response body

```
Download
{
  "timestamp": "2019-11-29T07:46:19.138+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/json",
  "path": "/ears/rest/v1/applications"
}
```

Для генерации данных описывающих API использую: springfox-swagger-ui, версия:2.9.2.

Поэтому не могу понять, это ошибка у меня в коде, либо в сгенерированном описании API?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD: Решение.**

Согласно [официальной документации](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/) загрузка произвольного количества файлов (массив файлов) не поддерживается. В середине ноября 2019 [закрыт запрос данной функции](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/254) для Swagger 2.0. По причине того, что OpenAPI 2 (Swagger 2.0) больше не находится в активной разработке.

Comment: а какое `body` вы отправляете в обоих случаях?

Comment: @raviga в Postmane JSON с установленным Content-type: application/json и файл (pdf, txt), с проставляемым типом автоматически. В Swagger UI, все аналогично, но все типы устанавливаются автоматически. Я добавляю только JSON  и прикрепляю файл.

Comment: Есь просто подозрения, что возможно проблема ак раз в хедерах. А можете добавить какие-то скриншоты хотя бы, как вы отправляете это на свагер и постман?

Comment: @raviga мне кажется я нашел ответ на проблему, даже 2 ответа.
1.https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2717 это то, что springfox-swagger-ui в RequestPart поддерживает только примитивные параметры.
2. https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/254 Swagger 2.0 не поддерживает для загрузки произвольный массив файлов.